# Dit-on d'une personne qu'elle est « à risque élevée des effets dangereux » d'une chose ?

Tags: prépositions, adjectifs, locutions, formulation-idiomatique, néologismes

Dans une mise en garde apparaissant sur l'emballage d'un produit on trouve par exemple :

> MISE EN GARDE : Les adolescents **sont à risque élevé** des effets
> dangereux du cannabis. Consommer du cannabis à l’adolescence peut
> augmenter le risque de devenir dépendant. ([source](https://www.canada.ca/fr/sante-canada/services/drogues-medicaments/cannabis/lois-reglementation/reglements-appuyant-loi-cannabis/mise-en-garde.html) ; [détails](https://laws-lois.justice.gc.ca/fra/reglements/DORS-2018-144/TexteComplet.html))
>
> ---
>
> WARNING: Adolescents are at greater risk of harms from cannabis. Using
> cannabis as a teenager can increase your risk of becoming addicted.
> ([source](https://www.canada.ca/en/health-canada/services/drugs-medication/cannabis/laws-regulations/regulations-support-cannabis-act/health-warning-messages.html))

Je trouve la première phrase inusitée ; est-ce usuel pour une personne *d'être [à risque](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=%C3%A0%20risque&id=3607) élevé d'un effet dangereux* ; le sens *être « exposé, prédisposé à un danger »* est-il compatible avec l'épithète *élevé* qualifiant le *risque*, y a-t-il confusion entre l'aménagement de la locution et du nom *risque* ; y a-t-il ellipse (du verbe) et redondance (de l'idée de *danger*) à la fois ; devrait-on choisir/ajouter une autre préposition (que *des*), un autre verbe, remanier la phrase ou la juge-t-on parfaitement claire et usuelle et peut-on expliquer pourquoi ?

Answer (score 1):

J'aurais d'abord été tenté de dire que cette tournure ne semblait pas naturelle et peut-être simplement calquée de l'anglais mais il se trouve qu'elle est attestée tant en France qu'au Québec comme le montre [cet article](http://www.linguatechediteur.com/auplaisirdesmots/peut-on-etre-a-risque) qui décrit l'apparition récente de la locution *à risque* et son évolution :

> **Modèle « *à risque de* + complément nominal »**
>
> Le modèle « ***à risque de*** + complément nominal » est nettement dominant dans les sites consultés, particulièrement les sites français. Exemples : personnes à risque de tuberculose; produits à risque de dépendance; femmes à risque de lapidation (attention, Hérouxville!); patients à risque de cirrhose; grossesses à risque de complications; personnes à risque de grippe aviaire. Mais on en trouve aussi des occurrences sur les sites québécois et canadiens. Exemples : élèves à risque de décrochage scolaire; pays à risque d'encéphalopathie bovine; individus à risque de mésadaptation.
>
> Robert Dubuc, 2007

Comment: Je crois que je m'attends au complément verbal (voire à aucun complément, à un autre adjectif en attribut) dans ce genre de phrase et contrairement à Rey je trouve que c'est parfaitement usuel et pas lourd du tout. Autrement je ne suis pas familier avec cet emploi avec le complément nominal, même s'il semble que oui pour un truc comme _élèves à risque de décrochage scolaire_, peut-être que c'est le _élevé_ et un complément nominal qui rappelle un complément verbal qui me dérange, je ne sais pas exactement pourquoi, ou simplement parce que c'est récent... peut-être indiquer attesté en 2005 ?

Answer (score 1):

Toutes ces formules me laissent moi aussi dubitatif.  A la lecture de la liste un peu fourre-tout que fournit Jiliagre, j'aurais tendance à penser qu'il s'agit d'un anglicisme mal digéré.

L'emploi absolu de *à risque* est bien accepté :

- une grossesse à risque
- une conduite à risque

Il me semble qu'on peut dans ce cas-là compléter par un adjectif qualifiant le degré du risque (élevé, réduit, faible…)

Pour en revenir à l'exemple donné, c'est une traduction officielle, elle fait foi, tout autant que la version anglaise, j'imagine.  Il faut donc l'accepter, mais je la trouve tout de même malheureuse.  Le traducteur fonctionnaire qui l'a pondue aurait pu se donner un peu plus de peine.  Je pense comme Suiiuriesse qu'il faudrait à tout le moins ajouter un verbe dans le complément de *risque élevé* :

- Les adolescents sont à risque élevé de subir les effets dangereux du cannabis.

Mieux :

- Les adolescents risquent plus de subir les effets dangereux du cannabis.

Comment: Pour une phrase qui soit vraiment naturelle je dirais plutôt « ont un risque élevé de subir ».

Comment: Je ne sais pas si on peut compléter l'emploi absolu par le degré de cette manière : _une grossesse à risque élevé_ ?? à risque élevé de quoi ? Je dirais plutôt _très risquée_ ou autrement _comportant un risque élevé de qqch_, un peu comme dans le propos de Stéphane où on n'est plus dans la locution. Par ailleurs je ne sais pas si c'est une traduction et perso. je ne trouve pas la phrase en anglais idiomatique et je trouve surprenant de rencontrer _adolescents_ (avec le mot différent _teenager_ la phrase d'après) et _harm_ au pluriel, entre autres. Au Canada le bilinguisme, c'est compliqué.

Comment: L'anglais est pas terrible, "harm" au pluriel est un peu curieux, mais je trouve le français pire.  Je ne sais pas comment sont rédigés les textes officiels au Canada mais il faut bien qu'à un moment donné, les versions soient alignées les unes sur les autres.  Y a-t-il un service centralisé chargé de la traduction ou chaque administration gère-t-elle ces questions de façon autonome?

Comment: Alignés certainement. Je ne suis pas au courant de tels détails mais on sait qu'ils ont un [_Bureau de la traduction_](https://www.tpsgc-pwgsc.gc.ca/bt-tb/index-fra.html) centralisé duquel relève Termium, par exemple... bien comme les mises en garde font l'objet d'une incorporation par référence dans un texte réglementaire relevant du ministère de la Justice ayant trait à une loi qui amende le Code criminel etc., on peut imaginer que ces mises en garde n'étaient pas le travail d'un simple fonctionnaire, mais c'est pure spéculation de ma part.